# file path problem

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll, filepath

I am working on the dll project which contain 3 module.All these module include comman header file.I have the include folder path like **mf/cv/include**.now In the property dialog box I have give the path in c/c++>>general>>additional inclde Directories like **.,..\include,..\cv\include** in all the 3 module. I the 2 module its work perfectely,but in the last module fatal error occur that

**fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'abc.h': No such file or
 directory**
So I am not not able to understand what the problem in the path bacause  this path work for all the module expect one.

Answer (score 0):

(By 3 modules, I assume you mean 3 projects.  If you meant 3 C++ files, you shouldn't be encountering this include problem.)

Instead of "..\include", try going into the property editor for that field and use the macros like $(SolutionPath)cv\include.  If you examine the macros it should tell you exactly where that target will be.